# Publishing Webpack wwwroot with CI

Tags: webpack, tfsbuild

I have an Angular 2 app that I am building with Webpack into wwwroot folder in my visual studio project. I want to deploy those changes using CI but whenever I kick off a build, the wwwroot folder is not updating in Azure. Does anyone have any sample build definitions that do what I am trying to do?

Comment: Do you mean you can use Webpack to build your application into the wwwroot folder in VS locally, now you want to have the same function from TFS build to Azure? Which version of TFS are you using? Do you use the tasks based build definition?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can use [webpack](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dealogic.webpack-vsts-extension) task to bundle JavaScript modules with webpack. Then use [Azure App Service Deploy](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/tree/master/Tasks/AzureRmWebAppDeployment) task to deploy to Azure Web App.